# Using single replacement rule to convert algebraic expression

Tags: programming, syntax, homework

I have been trying this problems for hours and cannot find any helpful clues.

How can I convert $Sinh[3\theta]+Sinh[\theta]$ to a rational function of x given $2Sinh[\theta] = x-x^{-1}$ by using only a **SINGLE** pattern replacement rule. I guess what single means is that we are only allowed to use one arrow.

My question is twofold:
1. I have one method but unsure of its correctness, also although I know the method but I am unable to write the code.
2. If my method is wrong, what is the correct one? This is the best method that I can think of.

My method is as follows:
Since we have the hyperbolic trig formula, we can use the rule (I will use Q instead)

```
Sinh[a Q] -> (x^a - x^-a)/2
```

I have tried many ways, and below are the 2 best ones that I think are the closest to the correct answers:

```
In: f := {Sinh[a Q] + Sinh[Q]} /. Sinh[a Q] -> (x^a - x^-a)/2;
In: {Sinh[3 Q]] + Sinh[Q]} // f
```

> `Out: {1/2 (-x^-a + x^a) + Sinh[Q]}[{Sinh[Q] + Sinh[3 Q]}]`

```
In: {Sinh[#1 Q] + Sinh[#2 Q]} /. Sinh[# Q] -> (x^# - x^-#)/2 &[3, 1]
```

> `Out: {1/2 (-(1/x^3) + x^3) + Sinh[Q]]}`

I always have troubles putting the rules into one entity such that it will replace every coefficient of Q, including 1. The output that I am looking for (using my method) is

```
Sinh[3Q] + Sinh[Q] = x^3 - x^-3 + x - x^-1
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Would `TrigToExp[Sinh[3 Q] + Sinh[Q]] /. Exp[a_. Q] -> 2 x^a` work ?

Comment: From your sentence _" I guess what single means is that we are only allowed to use one arrow."_ I infer this is homework. Am I right?

Comment: You might find [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PatternsInvolvingAlternatives.html) to be useful.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Thanks! yes your method works. I have never used TrigToExp before, but I have learned new things now.

Comment: @belisarius Yes, this is an exercise.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for Alternative. That will be very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using defaults values `_.` (for multiplication it is 1)  works:

```
{Sinh[3 Q] + Sinh[Q]} /. Sinh[a_. Q] -> (x^a - x^-a)/2
```

Comment: You should probably use `:>` to localize `a`

Comment: Great! Thanks so much Andrew. This is the first time I learn about defaults values. It is really helpful!